# How to read JSON string sent from the frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I've got this html code

```
<div id="loginform">
<form class="loginIn" name="loginform">
    <input type="text" name="login">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Войти">
</form>
```

```
<script>
    loginform.onsubmit = function () {
        var formData = new FormData(loginform);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/send", true);
        var data = {};
        for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
            data[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }

        var date = new Date();
        var hours = date.getHours();
        if (hours < 10){
            hours = hours + '0';
        }
        var mins = date.getMinutes();
        if (mins < 10){
            mins = mins + '0';
        }
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = date.getMonth()+1;

        time = 'Дата: ' + day  + '.' + month + ' | Время: ' + hours + ':' + mins;

        data.LoginTime = time;
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
</script>
```

It forms a JSON string, which i succesfully could read throughout req.read() without express.

So here the question: how do i can read the following string and operate with it using express?

Comment: do you have an express server set up? if so, would you be able to post some of the server code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an express server, you can use the body-parser to get the data from the request body.

For example:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.route.post('/send', function(req, res){

  console.log( req.body.LoginTime );
  res.send('done'); 
})
```

Additionally, your Html code has to specify the content type.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use body-parse in order to get the sent parameters from the client.

first download body-parse to your project

```
npm install body-parse --save
```

then you can write the service like that in express:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/send', (req, res)=>{
    console.log( req.body );
    res.send(req.body);
});
```